# Select a Portion of Vast Data Over Time with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have hundreds of thousands of price points spanning 40 years plus. I would like to construct a query that will only return 3000 total data points, with the last 500 being the most recent data points, and the other 2500 being just a sample of the rest of the data, evenly distributed.

Is it possible to do this in one query? How would I select just a sample of the large amount of data? This is a small example of what I mean for getting just a sample of the other 2500 data points:

```
1
2
3    
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

And I want to return something like this:

```
1
5
10
```

Here's the query for the last 500:

```
SELECT * FROM price ORDER BY time_for DESC LIMIT 500
```

I'm not sure how to go about getting the sample data from the other data points.

Comment: Can you show the design of the table? And how many records do you have?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
(SELECT * FROM price ORDER BY time_for DESC LIMIT 500)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM price WHERE time_for < (SELECT time_for FROM price ORDER BY time_for LIMIT 500, 1) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2500)
ORDER BY time_for
```

Note: It's probably going to be slow. How big is this table?

It might be faster to only get the primary ID from all these rows, then join it to the original in a secondary query once it's narrowed down. This is because `ORDER BY rand() LIMIT` has to sort the *entire* table. If the table is large this can take a LONG time, and a lot of disk space. Retrieving only the ID reduces the necessary disk space.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is good, but you did specify that you want the results to be *evenly distributed* so I'll add this possibility too. By iterating a counter over the rows you can use a MOD operator to sample an even distribution. I don't have a MYSQL install right now to test this so apologies if the syntax isn't 100% spot on. But it should be close enough and may give you some ideas.

```
  (  SELECT p1.*
       FROM price p1
   ORDER BY p1.time_for DESC
      LIMIT 500  )

   UNION ALL

  (  SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS row_num,
            p2.*
       FROM price p2,
            (SELECT @i: = 0)
      WHERE row_num > 500
        AND (row_num % 500) = 0
   ORDER BY time_for DESC  )
```

The first query gives the 500 latest rows. The second query gives every 500th row after that, thus returning an even distribution from the rest of the data. Obviously you can tune this parameter to achieve the desired sample spacing. Or base it on the total number of rows in the table to calculate the necessary spacing to give exactly 2500 records.